# How does SystemVerilog implement the dynamic features of the language?

Tags: hardware, fpga, system-verilog, hdl

I have started to learn SystemVerilog and I am reading about the new types, such as:

- strings
- dynamic/associative arrays
- queues

I am wondering how these can be implemented in hardware due to their dynamic nature; is it that they are only for testing/simulation purposes so they are never actually instantiated in hardware?

If so, why would you ever use those types of arrays if you had to change to a normal array to run the design on hardware?

Comment: They are features used for verification. SystemVerilog is a language used for design and verification

Comment: Note to reopen reviewers: This question is not too broad from the perspective of a hardware description language (HDL). The design goal for any HDL is to be synthseizable to a FPGA or ASIC, thereby requiring static implementations. The SO is asking why dynamic features that cannot synthesize are part of the language.

Comment: SystemVerilog consists of two parts, Verification and Design. Most of the types you mentioned are for simulation purpose like they are being used in SW programming language. However, strings are synthesizable if and only if it is viewed as vector of bytes, no dynamic stuffs like new/free and string methods.

Comment: Should the above comment be an answer instead?  That would get this off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog and now SystemVerilog contain features that fall into two categories: *Synthesizable* and *Non-Synthesizable*. There is no fixed standard that defines which features belong in each catagory. Ideally if you can simulate a feature, you can find a way to synthesize it.

Some features wind up in both categories depending on how it's used. For example, a `for` loop is synthesizable if you can statically determine (i.e. at compile time rather than run-time) how many iterations it has. The same is true for a queue or dynamic array - if you can define a maximum size, they can be implemented in hardware.